# Autoupdating userform for each loop without needing to response to the userform

Tags: excel, vba

I would like to know if it is possible to autoupdate a userform in VBA?

In my case:

```
    While Cells(57, 3) > (Cells(47, 3) - Cells(46, 3) + 0)

    Cells(52, 3) = Cells(52, 3) + 0.5

    Call foto_2

    Wend
```

As you can see in the code above, I have a loop where I change the value of a cell.

And the value of the cell is link up with a graphique

By calling `foto_2`, I am updating an image on the userform.

Here is the code in the userform which contain the image of `foto_2`,

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
Call foto_2
End Sub
```

while this is the code for the `foto_2`,

```
Sub foto_2()

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    Fname = ....    
    Sheets(1).ChartObjects("foto_2").Chart.Export Filename:=Fname, Filtername:="GIF"

    UserForm1.Image1.Picture = LoadPicture(Fname)

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in your foto_2 procedure, place a DoEvents after the last line:

```
Sub foto_2()

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Fname = ....    
Sheets(1).ChartObjects("foto_2").Chart.Export Filename:=Fname, Filtername:="GIF"

UserForm1.Image1.Picture = LoadPicture(Fname)
DoEvents

End Sub
```

Comment: when should I call the Userform to be activated?

Comment: Your while loop above is in a module right? Just place a line before the while loop like this to load the userform:
    UserForm1.Show

Comment: the problem is that when i open the userform, i need to respons to the userform to get the loop started, whereas i was thinking that the userform will show the loop simulate.